# Is it safe to put wooden louver doors on my boiler closet?

Tags: hvac

My boiler is contained under my staircase in the basement.  I have finished my basement, making it a living space.  Can I put wooden louver doors in front of the boiler, about 1-1/2 ft out? Is that safe?

Comment: Every heating device has instructions on how close flammable material can be to each side of it.   There should also be a clear working area for maintenance.

Comment: gas or electric boiler ?

Comment: If you post the brand/model for _your_ furnace, someone might be nice enough to search for the installation manual that will tell you exactly how close things can be to it.

Comment: You have to worry about 1) distance to flammable material and for some boilers, 2) air flow for combustion.   The boiler instructions probably give you guidance on both.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a great deal on the equipment you have.

I have a high-efficiency boiler which is so good at sending the heat into the water (and the remainder out the exhaust) that its manufacturer says I can put flammable materials right up against it safely. For the boiler that preceded it, a 3-foot clear space on all sides was recommended. So first step is to get and read the manuals.

Next step, as others have said, would be to check with your local building inspector's office, explain exactly what you want to do (a diagram helps) and ask if they would consider it acceptable under code and local rules or not. They would much rather answer questions before you start than have to deal with it later.

Having said all that: there are times when it's OK to violate code, as long as you put things back in code-compliant form before transferring ownership to anyone else. But those are generally in the category of "if you have any least doubt, don't." Code usually has good reasons for its rules.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CODE, what you can and can not do.

Installing wooden louver doors so close to the heat source might not be permitted.

However if you use metal (steel) louver doors you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

WAIT A SECOND.....This isn't about the flammability of the doors or how close they are permitted to be to your unit. The issue is maintaining the fire rating of the room! Most boiler rooms are required to have a double layer or thicker single layer of sheetrock to provide a 2 hour fire rating. A wooden louvered door erodes that fire rating.
It appears you didn't apply for a CO for this finished space otherwise this topic would've been addressed. Even if you are choosing not to file for a permit/CO you should make sure your furnace has enough fresh air and a proper door is installed. There are reasons behind codes - inconvenient or not. You're playing with fire (literally) and carbon monoxide issues.
As for the answer that states "there are times when it's OK to violate code, as long as you put things back in code-compliant form before transferring ownership to anyone else." Is absolutely ridiculous with regards to a furnace. Yes, people do violate codes and are forced to rectify it when selling the home, but to say "it's ok" is just plain stupid. If we were talking about violating how far a shed is to the property line is one thing, but when it comes to life safety issues - you'd better do the right thing. It wouldn't be "ok" if someone died as result of a fire or carbon monoxide poisoning caused by violating code. Saying "I was going to fix it before I sold the house" wouldn't help much. It's never good to blindly trust answers on a DIY forum -this is a topic worth seriously investigating.